# Unknown key in PDF object's dictionary

Tags: pdf

Assume that you have a couple of objects in PDF file.

What behaviour is expected if object's dictionary contains a key, which **is not defined/described** in *PDF 32000-1:2008* standard?

Comment: It does depend on what kind of program you think of. In case of a PDF debugging tool you may want to indicate everything suspicious while in an end-user viewer you may choose to ignore unknown keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [PDF 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) compatibility rules, described in Appendix I.3 covers this:

> When a new version of PDF is defined, many features are introduced simply by adding new entries to existing
>   dictionaries. Earlier versions of conforming readers do not notice the existence of such entries and behave as if
>   they were not there. Such new features are therefore both forward- and backward-compatible.  Likewise,
>   adding entries not described in the PDF specification to dictionary objects does not affect the conforming
>   reader’s behavior.

In short, extraneous dictionary entries are ignored.

Comment: That been said, there now are mechanisms to indicate PDF extension levels and to mark private keys with prefixes. If the OP creates a PDF tool for *PDF developers*, therefore, he may want to display a warning (on a separate tab) if he finds a non-standard key which cannot be explained via such a mechanism.